# Teradata query, RBAC profile

Tags: sql, teradata, rbac

The below query I use to see if I have access to a table in Teradata. I also want to know what RBAC role/profile I need for access to a particular table/schema. I remember having code to do this before. However, I cannot find the code anymore. Is there any code in teradata that I can see what RBAC profile has access to which tables/schemas. Also, is there code for the opposite? So, given a table/schema in Teradata, is there a way to get the access RBAC profile with grants to that table/schema. Thanks for your help.

```
EXEC PUBLIC_GLOBAL.DescribeView('SCHEMA.TABLE')
```

Comment: This `PUBLIC_GLOBAL.DescribeView` is non-standard, don't know what it returns. You probably to know which role is needed to access a table? There's view `dbc.AllRoleRightsV` covering role access rights.

Answer (score 0):

All I could find was this. Looks like this data is housed on a report for consumption.

```
SELECT  *
FROM dbc.allrights
WHERE username='user-id'
AND databasename='database-name'
```

Comment: Should be `dbc.allrightsV`, but this doesn't include role rights